# How do you use the "here document" in eval function?

Tags: shell, eval

I have a shell script (test.sh) in which I am using the `eval()` function to run commands by reading them from a file "config.txt" e.g.

```
cat config.txt
ntpq -p
date
```

`eval()` in the script uses "cat" to get one command from each line.

How can I use the "here document" in the config.txt so that I don't have to change the script and `eval()` still executes it (meaning here document should be in one line)?

Perhaps something like this:

`command << EOF\n1st\n2nd\nEOF`

Comment: Not sure what the question means... Also, add a question mark at the end.

Comment: `config.txt` is for all intents and purposes a script. Just source it.

Comment: If the contents of config.txt is really just individual commands one-per-line then do what @chepner says and just source the script instead of using eval.